# Switching Branches causes database does not exist error when testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, cloud9

I recently set up postgresql in a new workspace. I set it up the same way I usually do. Or at least I thought I did. But then I got this error

```
Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError:
  FATAL:  database "app_test" does not exist
```

It only happens when I change to a branch and run rspec. So far I've just been creating the database and running migrations each time I switch between branches as a solution.

It doesn't impact the development database. And as long as I remain on that branch I don't have to add the test database again. But if I have to leave it for any reason, I'll have to add the database again.

It seems to impact any branch that isn't the master. And this only occurs locally. I am using Cloud 9 and my app is a Rails app. Should I uninstall and reinstall postgresql, then set it up again?

Recently I've had to work on a few branches at the same time, so it's becoming a hassle. I'm tempted to just make a new workspace.

here is my database.yml(with some things hidden of course, app is a stand in for my app's name).

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: secret
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you run `rake db:test:prepare` after switching branches, but before running `rspec`, does it work?

Comment: It gives me an error 
```Caused by: PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR: new encoding (UTF8) is incompatible with the encoding of the template database (SQL_ASCII) HINT: Use the same encoding as in the template database, or use template0 as template.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to reset your databases by running:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:test:prepare
```

That'll delete your dev database (along with any data in it), recreate it, rebuild the schema from your migration files, and rebuild the test database. If it doesn't work at that point you may be a permissions issue

Comment: I did the `rake db:drop` but when I did `rake db:create` I got this error 
```
Caused by:
PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  new encoding (UTF8) is incompatible with the encoding of the template database (SQL_ASCII)
HINT:  Use the same encoding as in the template database, or use template0 as template.
```

Comment: Ah, you might have to configure Postgres to use unicode by default. Looks like it's set to ASCII right now.

Comment: Okay so I got your way to work, NM Pennypacker! I first dropped all my branches (I already had all their changes remotely).Then I added `template:template: template0` to my database.yml and followed your directions. RSpec runs fine now on my branches. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced with similar issue.
Just try to change this line of database.yml

host: 127.0.0.1

when i provided localhost it used default settings for connection. (i have many DB server version on different ports)

Answer (score 0):

1. First I deleted my local branches to start clean (it may not be necessary but as most of them altered the schema I thought it'd be cleaner). My changes where all stored remotely so this was wasn't a big deal.
2. Then I added `template: template0` to my database.yml in the development and test sections. I followed this suggestion [Fix for PG::Error: ERROR: new encoding (UTF8) is incompatible](https://gist.github.com/amolkhanorkar/8706915#gistcomment-1317424)
   because I had this error:

"PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  new encoding (UTF8) is incompatible with the encoding of the template database (SQL_ASCII)
HINT: Use the same encoding as in the template database, or use template0 as template."

whenever I would try to use `rake db:create`

3. After that I followed NM Pennypacker's guidance and did, `rake db:drop`, `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:test:prepare`.
   I've made some branches, pulled in the remote changes and run rspec with no problem. Thank you everyone for your advice!